# Equivalent of Python's Pass in Scala

Tags: python, scala

If there is a function that you don't want to do anything with you simple do something like this in Python:

```
def f():
    pass
```

My question is, is there something similar to `pass` in Scala?

Comment: Pass exists in Python because of the indentation based syntax. Pass is needed to illustrate an empty code block. In languages that use braces, it's almost always something like {}.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pass` is a syntactic quirk of Python. There are some cases where the grammar *requires* you to write a statement, but sometimes you don't want a statement there. That's what `pass` is for: it's a statement that does nothing.

Scala never requires you to write a statement, therefore the way to not write a statement is simply to not write a statement.

Comment: actually there are use cases where scala requires a pass equivalent. Consider a simple example: We have a function which returns a unit but the last statement has some return value (which we want to ignore). A pass equivalent (e.g. () or Unit) is required in this case.

Comment: That's totally different. `pass` is an actual no-op for cases where a statement is *syntactically* required, but you don't actually want a statement there. E.g. you simply want an empty function, but the grammar requires at least one statement in a function. What you talk about is simply wanting to return the correct value. That's a semantic issue, not a syntactic one.

Answer (score 13):

I think `()` is similar.

```
scala> def f() = ()
f: ()Unit

scala> f              

scala>
```

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect AFAIK. This is correct.

Answer (score 4):

As i understand in python `pass` is used for *not yet implemented* cases. If you need such thing in scala then use `???` it's similar to `()`, but is a function returning Nothing (`def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError`) . Your code will compile, but if you call such a method it will crash with `NotImplementedError`

```
def foo: ResultType = ???
```

Comment: No. "pass is a null operation -- when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed"

Comment: But in Scala, statements are never required syntactically, you can just leave it out.

Comment: @4lex1v, theres an error in your answer, ??? is NOT an instance of Nothing. infact Nothing doesnot have any values or instances. ??? is a function returns Nothing type. ie. throws an Exception. this is the code : "def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError"

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can substitute `Unit` for `pass`. You do nothing and the line evaluates to `Unit`, similar to Java's `void`, but itself an explicit type.

```
// implicit return value of type Unit
def showMsg(msg:Option[String]) = msg match {
    case None => Unit
    case Some(m) => println(m)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

say you create a stub for a function that will return a string

you can add `""` as a placeholder and your function will compile

Before

```
❯ cat TrainingSet.scala
def getCommitMessage(x: String): String = {
}

❯ ./TrainingSet.scala
cat: /Users/lgeoff/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/release: No such file or directory
/Volumes/workplace/migrate_ant_to_gradle/./TrainingSet.scala:59: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
  def getCommitMessage(x: String): String = {
                                            ^
one error found
```

After

```
❯ cat TrainingSet.scala
def getCommitMessage(x: String): String = {
    ""
}

❯ ./TrainingSet.scala
❯
```